# How to bind XmlDataProvider from ViewModel to ListBox?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, binding

I'm having trouble binding XmlDataProvider from ViewModel (my DataContext) to ListBox's ItemsSource.

This is what I did -

In Xaml -

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedXmlProvider}">...</ListBox>
```

In my ViewModel class -

```
public XmlDataProvider SelectedFeedXmlProvider
{
    get { return _selectedFeedXmlProvider; }
    set
    {
        _selectedFeedXmlProvider = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedFeedXmlProvider");
    }
}
```

In my application -

```
viewModel.SelectedFeedXmlProvider =  new XmlDataProvider
{
    Source = new Uri("http://sxp.microsoft.com/feeds/3.0/MSDNTN/CSharpHeadlines"),
    XPath = "//item"
};
```

And... ListBox is EMPTY! (where it should have been full with data).

When setting the ListBox's ItemsSource to an XmlDataProvider that's defined as a static resource, all is fine. Thing is, I must use MVVM, and I need to be able to dynamically change the XML source.

Can someone help? what's wrong with the code above? why is the list empty?

Thanks!

Comment: it could be that listBox is not accepting XmlDataProvider items as value. what's your Output saying?
u can try to save yuur items in a list and then Display the list in yuur ListBox

Comment: But it does accept XmlDataProvider when it's a static resource (like in Window.Resources)

Comment: u r binding on SelectedXmlProvider. can I see the property too or did you a mistake and it should be SelectedFeedXmlProvider?

Comment: Thanks, Dennis. The code has already been changed too much to be able to see the possible (and stupid) mistake you're talking about. However, I decided not to look back, and take your initial suggestion - to build the list and bind to it. And it works! thanks a lot!